# What is the best way to enumerate a list in natural language (Scala)?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The `List` object has the `mkString` method that will can convert to a string with a seperator. However most human languages treats the last element different when enumerating a list. For example A, B, C and D.

What is the best in terms of code size and reasonable efficiency to accomplish this? To be precise, I am searching for a function that satisfies:

```
assertEquals("",foo(List()))
assertEquals("A",foo(List("A")))
assertEquals("A and B",foo("List("A","B")))
assertEquals("A, B and C", foo(List("A","B","C")))
assertEquals("A, B, C and D", foo(List("A","B","C","D")))
```

Comment: But what about the Oxford Comma? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def foo(xs: List[String]) = 
  (xs.dropRight(2) :\ xs.takeRight(2).mkString(" and "))(_+", "+_)
```

**edit**: This might be a bit clearer:

```
def foo(xs: List[String]) = 
  (xs.dropRight(2) :+ xs.takeRight(2).mkString(" and ")).mkString(", ")
```

@axaluss The speed depends on the list length. With an average list length above about 4 elements, this second version is faster than Tomasz's. Otherwise, it's slightly slower.

Comment: is your version the fastest one? atleast its the shortest ;)

Answer (score 8):

My take:

```
def foo[T](list: List[T]): String = list match {
    case Nil => ""
    case x :: Nil => x.toString
    case x :: y :: Nil => x + " and " + y
    case x :: rs => x + ", " + foo(rs)
}
```

Also to utilize tail recursion:

```
@tailrec def str[T](cur: String,  list: List[T]): String = list match {
    case Nil => cur
    case x :: Nil => cur + x
    case x :: y :: Nil => cur + x + " and " + y
    case x :: rs => str(cur + x + ", ", rs)
}

def foo[T](list: List[T]) = str("", list)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def foo(list: List[String]) = list match{
  case Nil => ""
  case _ if list.length == 1 => list.first
  case _ => list.init.mkString(", ") + " and " + list.last
}
```

Comment: Here is my own version: `def naturalMakeString(list: List[Any], sep1: String, sep2: String) = if (list.length<2) list.mkString else list.init.mkString(sep1)+sep2+list.last` however both yours and mine are neither short nor efficient (uses of init and last)

Comment: Using `x :: Nil => x` as the second case, and `case x => x.init...` as the third is a bit shorter